# How to set expiry for the CouchBase using couchnode

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am storing the data in CouchBase from Node.js app using the following codes ([couchnode](https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode) client):

```
    //Expiry information of couchbase doucumenets. fetched from config.json
    //Expiry is less than 30*24*60*60 (30 days)
    //The value is interpreted as the number of seconds from the point of storage or update.
    //Expiry is greater than 30*24*60*60
    //The value is interpreted as the number of seconds from the epoch (January 1st, 1970).
    //Expiry is 0
    //This disables expiry for the item. 
    CouchBaseDB.set(keytosave, 60, doctosave, function (err, meta) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); } else {console.log('saved');}
    });
```

Unfortunately, the above code is not working (its saving 60 itself instead of object `doctosave`) and no where its explained how to set expiry othere than [Chapter 4. Java Method Summary - 4.4. Expiry Values](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-java-1.0/couchbase-sdk-java-summary-expiry.html).

Does any one came across the same and found any work-around/solution or any document support for the same. If explained it would be of great HELP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set function looks like this:

```
function set(key, doc, meta, callback) { ... }
```

If you want to add expiry for stored key just create `meta = {}` object and add field expiry to it: `meta.expiry = 1000`.

Here is link to [sources](https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/master/lib/bucket.js#L277)

So to store your doc you need:

```
var meta = {"expiry":60};
CouchBaseDB.set(keytosave, doctosave, meta, function (err, meta) {
  if (err) { console.log(err); } else {console.log('saved');}
});
```

Note: Also if that key is retreived form couchbase via `CouchBaseDB.get()`, `meta` could be extracted from that get function.

Comment: Please also note that if you provide an `expiry` greater than `2592000` (the number of seconds in 1 month), it is interpreted as a unix timestamp.

Reference: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/developer/dev-guide-3.0/doc-expiration.html